# Resize shapefile

Tags: python, visualization

I have a shapefile for each US state and I would like to add all shapefiles together which I do using `Basemap` and `readshapefile` and so on.
Now my problem is that Alaska is huge and doesn't fit into the map.
I would like to add Alaska extra in the west of Texas (left bottom corner) which is the normal approach to solve this problem.
Therefore I manipulated the shapefile of Alaska to move the shape using this code:

```
for t in range(len(shape)):
            l = list(shape[t])
            l[1] -= 4000000
            l[0] += 1000000
            tup = tuple(l)
            shape[t] = tup
```

Well as I mentioned Alaska is huge so is there any easy way to resize the shapefile?

Thanks for your ideas!

**Edit:**

Some additional information:
I am using the whole thing to visualize the Census 2013 data. My current output looks like this: https://goo.gl/photos/RKMGcmw7ig7MNHv56

Projection: Albers Equal Areas

Comment: I have edited your question to read more correctly by popular Geo-spatial terminology

Comment: Actually I don't want to shift them but to resize it. Shifting ist working already ;)

Comment: Ah okay.. I misunderstood.. are you then trying to like reduce the alska in size after moving it next to texas? :)

Comment: Yes cause the size of Alaska is around 20% the size of the USA ;)

Comment: Gotcha..  check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoa, wait a second.

There is no "resizing" in GIS. Not without losing important geospatial properties of your geometries. You should not do that.

First of all, what is the purpose of this map? What tools are you using to render it? In what geospatial projection (different projections have different properties, making maps look very different when rendered)?

The traditional approach around this is to render two maps and compose them, as images. If you move the shapefiles, you WILL lose the coordinates and you won't be able to generate, let's say, correct graticule lines for Alaska.

If this is just one time thing, you can perhaps move it or resize, but I strongly advise against that.

Comment: I am analysing the Census data of the USA from 2013:
https://goo.gl/photos/RKMGcmw7ig7MNHv56
And I would like to include Alaska inside the map. Therefore I am using different shapefiles inside my Python script. The shapefiles: ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/PUMA/

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one time thing and Unless you *have* to do this programatically, I would say easiest way is to download a free tool like [OpenJump](http://www.openjump.org/), Open up your Alaska shapefile along with the USA Border shapefile, and just resize it like you would in Photo Shop :).. you can also precisely perform your translation too :)